# A sum of root of $-1$ modulo n

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

> Find the sum of positive integers $n$ less than $2021$ such that $n^{3 \cdot 7 \cdot 23} \equiv -1 \pmod{2021}$.

I was making an elementary number theory problem using the year number $2021=43 \cdot 47$. Of course the number of solution is $21 \times 23= 483$. By the way, I have calculated the sum of all solutions to get $493124$ which is exactly $2021 \cdot (483+5)/2$.
The exponent $3 \cdot 7 \cdot 23$ is $\varphi(2021)/4$.
I wonder if there could be a systemetic explanation about the result.
Thanks for your attention.

PS: After some test on the other numbers, I guess the number $483+5$ is fairly random consquence of the distribution of the solution. Therefore, any systemetic explanation without counting all the solutions on some interval, if any, likely to be very hard.

Comment: Well the sum modulo $m$ is either $0,\frac{m-1}{2}$

Comment: Try simplifying it, such as (I'll do a smaller case that is not related to the question)

$2^{42} $ mod $3 = 2^{3}\times{14}=-1^{14} $mod $3 = 1.$

$2^3=8=-1$ mod $3$.

Comment: @AaaLol_dude:  did you mean $2^{3\times14}$?

Comment: Yes LaTeX kinda needing braces tripping me out